# Implement Solr Search into Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-solr

I am trying to implement solr search into one of my rails project. My problem statement is to be able to search upon my models and show relevant results along with auto suggest. Could someone help me to complete it properly. At the moment I am trying to use sunspot solr although its not working for me as expected. I can see some indexing has been created in my project but the search is not working. Also there is no gem for auto suggest. Below are some snippets of my code. And yes I have gone through other links for solr and it did not solve my problem.

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :parent_category_id, :image, :image_file_name,     :image_content_type, :image_file_size
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events, :join_table => :categories_events

  has_attached_file :image

  searchable do
    text :name
  end

end
```

My Controller

```
if params.has_key?(:category)
  puts "Inside Index Search"
  puts params[:category]
  @search = Category.ransack do 
    fulltext params[:category]
  end
  @category = @search.result.first
```

I am getting the results into @category and using it in my view to display.

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate your help. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. There was a conflict between Solr and Ransack gem and that's why I could not get the resultset. It needed the below changes and its working now.

```
    @search = Sunspot.search(Category) do 
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @category = @search.results
```

**EDIT**

My answer might not seem complete so just adding the code snippet that worked for me.

My Model

```
searchable do
    text :name, :as => :name_textp
    text :description, :as =>  :description_textp
    text :category_strings, :as => :category_strings_textp
    string :get_valid_dates, :multiple => true
    integer :category_ids, :multiple => true
    boolean :active
    boolean :company_display
end
```

My Controller

```
search_results = Sunspot.search(Event) do
    fulltext current_search
    with(:category_ids, [ id ])
    with(:active, true)
    with(:company_display, true)
    paginate(:page => @current_page, :per_page => page_size)
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd be interested in how to avoid this namespace collission.

Comment: "Conflict" is the wrong term here. "Calling the wrong method" is more like it.

Comment: Well I don't remember the error now. Its being some time. Though after hours of googling I had read something about some conflicts between the two gems. I will try to find the article and update it here. :-)

Answer (score 3):

What does the method Category.ransack do ? I assume that you are using sunspot gem to integrate Solr into your project. If so use Category.search to search you index. Then use

```
@search.results
```

not

```
@search.result
```

So your code should look like this:

```
@search = Category.search do 
    fulltext params[:category]
end

@category = @search.results.first
```

You can also write it shorter:

```
@category = Category.search do 
   fulltext params[:category] 
end.results.first
```

Remember that before you can use index in Solr, you have run:

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

If you are looking for information about implementing autocomplete on Solr, please read this article: http://olgagr.github.io/ruby/solr/how-to-implement-autocomplete-with-solr-and-ruby-on-rails

Some time ago I also struggled with this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It conflicts of **Solr** & **Ransack** method ***search***.

So please user **solr_search** instead of **search**

ex:

```
search = Product.solr_search do
  fulltext 'random'
end
search.results
```